# static и безопасность

Tags: c#

Пусть имеется некий объект, выполняющий какую-то криптографическую операцию (например `KeyedHashAlgorithm`, `SymmetricAlgorithm` или `AsymmetricAlgorithm`).

Скажем, объект для хэширования паролей

```
KeyedHashAlgorithm keyedSha512 = KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create("HMACSHA512");
```

который каким-то образом инициализируется

```
keyedSha512.Key = ...;
```

Чтобы вычислить хэш пароля можно создавать и инициализировать новый объект всякий раз, когда он потребуется.

Предположим, однако, что при инициализации ключ загружается с другого хоста, т.е. инициализация может быть относительно долгой. В этом случае, в целях оптимизации, просится создание и инициализацию крипто-объекта выполнить один раз, поместив его в `static` поле какого-то класса, где он будет жить, пока приложение запущено.

Понизит ли это каким-либо образом безопасность? Каковы рекомендации и best-pracices на этот счёт?

Comment: можете кешировать, но только зашифрованным. Но только не забывайте, что у Вас управляемый язык с GC. А это значит, что даже если Вы будете каждый раз создавать объект и потом удалять, ещё не значит, что в памяти его не будет.

Comment: Для хранения секретов нужно использовать возможности системы, для Windows это Crypto API. Хранение секрета в поле класса, равносильно выходу на улицу и выкрикиванию оного.

Comment: Огласите вашу модель угроз. Без неё говорить о безопасности не имеет смысла. Например, если вы сражаетесь против враждебного кода, бегущего с вашими правами или правами администратора, то не поможет ничего, по сути.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала надо определиться с вектором атаки и от чего вы защищаетесь. Если сервер, на котором запущено приложение ваш и полностью вами контролируется, то вы не потеряете в безопасности, а возможно и приобретёте, ибо не будете каждый раз за ключом ходить удалённо на другой хост, т.е. перехватить трафик с ключом будет сложнее.

Если сервер не ваш, и распложен удалённо, тут сложнее. Можно снять дамп памяти приложения и получить ключ (он будет храниться в `KeyValue` у `KeyedHashAlgorithm`), также если приложение запущено на виртуальной машине у хостера - можно снять дамп виртуальной машины целиком. Ну и совсем из страшного - заморозить планку памяти жидким азотом и снять её содержимое.

При этом, стоит иметь в виду, что в .NET остатки ключа в любом случае останутся где-нибудь в куче после Garbage Collector, так что создание объекта каждый раз не гарантирует ничего. Можете использовать `SecureString` где возможно, но его неудобно использовать и не всё API в .NET поддерживает его.

Так что, скорее всего, вы ничего не потеряете, если будете хранить криптообъект или сам ключ в памяти своего приложения, если у вас нет специфических требований.

Answer (score 2):

Может быть пригодится кому-то ещё.

Чтобы уменьшить время нахождения ключа в памяти в открытом виде, я решил воспользоваться функционалом класса [ProtectedData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx), который использует возможности *Data Protection API* (DPAPI).

Вместо

```
static KeyedHashAlgorithm keyedSha512 = KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create("HMACSHA512");
```

статическим я сделал шифрованный ключ (а также энтропию - дополнительный параметр, используемый в методах класса `ProtectedData`):

```
static byte[] encrKey = null;
static byte[] entropy = new byte[64];
```

Инициализация статических полей выглядит следующим образом:

```
using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
    rng.GetBytes(entropy);

byte[] key = ...; //получаем ключ
encrKey = ProtectedData.Protect(key, entropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
Array.Clear(key, 0, key.Length);
```

т.е. генерируем энтропию, получаем ключ, шифруем его и очищаем нешифрованный.

Затем, при необходимости вычислить хэш, создаётся крипто-объект, ключ дешифруется, вычисляется хэш, после чего нешифрованный ключ очищается.

```
byte[] hash = null;
using (var keyedSha512 = KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create("HMACSHA512"))
{
    byte[] key = ProtectedData.Unprotect(encrKey, entropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
    keyedSha512.Key = key;
    hash = keyedSha512.ComputeHash(...);
    Array.Clear(key, 0, key.Length);
}
```

---

При использовании в IIS потребуется включить загрузку профиля пользователя (установить в True свойство "Load User Profile" соответствующего Application Pool).

Comment: Вы уверены, что Array.Clear не будет выброшен оптимизатором, и что не нужно другое API, ориентированное на безопасность?

Comment: @VladD, я думал об этом. Не уверен. Однако, я вижу использование Array.Clear, например, в методе Dispose класса KeyedHashAlgoritm ([здесь](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/keyedhashalgorithm.cs)). Должен ли я также делать `key = null`? Буду благодарен, если подскажете как сделать правильнее.

Comment: Я не знаю, я не эксперт, и мой совет может только навредить. Я руководствуюсь этой статьёй: https://habrahabr.ru/post/181372/